# Finding the heavy ball -- (minimum number of measurements)

Tags: combinatorics

I am looking at the famous coin puzzle :

```
      We are given a set of N numbered items, say balls.
   From them N-1 have identical weights and one is heavier. Our task is to 
   identify the heavier ball using balance scales with the restriction that no 
   standerd weights are provided. Thus the only possible way to perform a 
   measurement is to put some balls in one pan, some other balls
   in the other pan, and observe the result. There are three possible 
   outcomes from any such measurement: the left pan goes down, the right pan 
   goes down, or both pans are balanced.
   We have to achieve our goal with as few measurements as possible
```

Now for example when N=9 ,the leaves are 9 meaning we have 9 possibilities and  our tree is ternary so the answer is 
$$\lceil log_{3}9 \rceil$$
But when N=12 ,we have 24 leaves ,the tree is ternary and the answer is $$\lceil log_{3}24 \rceil$$.
My question is how do we decide the number of leaves given N as in the examples if N=9 then the leaves are 9 but if N=12 the leaves are 24.And how do we decide if our three is ternary?Is it because we have 3 states on the weight(up,down,balanced)?

Comment: I don't know how $24$ can come up.  Each weighing has either two or three possible outcomes (if the heavy coin is known to be on the scale, balancing is not possible), but $24 = 3 \times 2^3$, and that, it seems to me, can only come up with (at least) four weighings.

Comment: The correct answer for $N = 12$ is in fact three weighings, achievable in a couple of different ways, but I don't see how the answer above was arrived at.

Answer (score 0):

In case of, say $7$ balls we can do the following calculation.

Since $7$ is an odd number, we select one ball randomly then we put $3$ balls in one of the pans and $3$ balls in the other pan. We have a chance, $\frac17$,that we selected the heavier ball first. In this case the rest of the balls balance. If they don't then we will need a second measurement with the heavier three balls. (The heavier one among the three balls can be selected with only one measurement.) So, the expected number of the measurements in the case of $7$ balls is

$$E_7=1\frac17+(1+1)\frac67.$$

But we can write this the following way: In the case of an odd $n$ the expected number of measurements is
$$E_n=1\frac1n+\left(1+E_{\frac{n-1}2}\right)\frac{n-1}n.\tag 1$$
If $n$ is even then computing the expected number of measurements is simpler:
$$E_n=1+E_{\frac{n}2}.\tag 2$$
Now,
$$E_2=1,\ E_3=1,\ E_4=2,\ E_5=\frac15+E_2\frac45=\frac95,\ E_6=2,\ E_7=\frac{13}7.$$
In general it would be tough to find a closed form, but based on $(1)$ and $(2)$ the computation can be performed. (The problem is that the expected number of measurements depends on the prim factorization of the number of balls.)

For instance, in the case of $12$ balls, we have

$$E_{12}=1+E_{6}=1+1+E_3=3.$$
Or in the case of $20$:
$$E_{20}=1+E_{10}=2+E_5=2+\frac95=\frac{19}5.$$

Or even for $100$ balls
$$E_{100}=1+E_{50}=2+E_{25}=2+\frac1{25}+\frac{24}{25}E_{12}=2+\frac1{25}+\frac{24}{25}3.$$

---

The following diagram depicts the expected number of measurements for different numbers of balls. The red curve (fitting quite well) is the graph of $\operatorname{log}_{(2.4)}x.$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The tree is ternary because there are three possible outcomes for each weighing.  The number of leaves is simply equal to the number of possible "correct answers".  If one of $N$ balls is heavier than the rest, and you need to determine which one, then there are $N$ leaves, and the depth of the tree is *at least* $\left\lceil \log_3 N\right\rceil$.  (This is only a lower bound; for some types of problem it will take more weighings than this.)  If one ball is heavier or lighter, but you don't know which ball or whether it's heavier or lighter, then there are $2N$ leaves.  If one ball is heavier and one is lighter than the rest, then there are $N(N-1)$ leaves... etc.